# Using DataTables.net in Visual Studio Razor Pages (C#)

Tags: c#, html, css, razor, datatables

I'm trying to use the DataTables js addon from DataTables.net in a project of mine that uses Razor Pages. However, it just doesn't want to work and I can't figure out why. I set it up in VS Code to test it out, and it worked just fine for the test. Here is the code and a screenshot of the output:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#myTable').DataTable();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
                    <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
                    <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

However, when I try to do the same thing in VS 2019 using Razor Pages, nothing happens, it just prints the unformatted table. Here is the code and a screenshot I have for that.

```
@page
@model CustomerPageTest.Pages.Customer.ListModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "List";
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTable').dataTable();
    });
</script>

<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

As you can see, the two programs are very similar, just a little bit of a different syntax. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console when you load the Razor page? I notice you are mixing `http` and `https` in your resources. Perhaps see if you can get the `DataTables` from `https`??

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet from the default _Layout.cshtml file:

```
<div class="container">
    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
        @RenderBody()
    </main>
</div>

<footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
    <div class="container">
        &copy; 2020 - RazorPages.Test - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
    </div>
</footer>

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

The view you are editing gets injected into the final HTML file when `@RenderBody()` is called. However, this is above a handful of scripts at the bottom of the file.

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

The first script in the list is another instance of JQuery. This means that in the resulting HTML file, you are loading JQuery two different times. When the second instance of JQuery gets loaded, it is clearing out the additional functions that the DataTables -script adds onto the JQuery object, which is why the table is not loading as expected.

To fix this issue, you can load your scripts in the view in a Razor section.

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Or, you can leave the view as is and remove JQuery from _Layout.cshtml.